# How to do an accent insensitive grep?

Tags: encoding, grep, matching, diacritics, iconv

Is there a way to do an accent insensitive search using grep, preferably keeping the --color option ? By this I mean `grep --secret-accent-insensitive-option aei` would match àei but also äēì and possibly æi.

I know I can use `iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` to remove accents from a text, but I don't see how I can use it to match since the text is transformed (it would work for grep -c or -l)

Comment: In theory, you could normalize the input to NFD and transform the input regex into one which allows optional joining diacritics at any point.

Comment: You mean turning my example search string aei into something like [áâàä][éêèë][íîìï] and the like ? Yes, I could do it manually but probably forget many combinations. Is there a way to generate it from existing tables ? I mean the TRANSLIT from iconv already knows all the possibilities, so why reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: No, I mean [normalize](http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) any ä to a+[combining diaeresis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm) etc, then craft a regex to ignore any combining characters. I'd imagine `grep -P` should support the [`\p{...}` construct from Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties), but I haven't tested. So then your regex would look someting like `a\p{Mn}*e\p{Mn}*i\p{Mn}*` where the last `\p{Mn}*` could most likely be omitted (but that might break coloring).

Comment: OK, I'm reading you link but I'm not sure I understand the idea. Is it to match a vowel followed by any kind of accent (considering the unicode char as two bytes) ? \p{Mn} is for non-spacing marks and I'm not sure if that means only accents. Also why the * ? Anyway, it doesn't seem to work in a UTF-8 shell.

Comment: This colorizes "När" for me as expected: `perl -CSD -le 'print "--Na\x{0308}r--"' | grep --color -P '(\p{L}\p{Mn}*)+'`.  The `*` repeat is to allow multiple stacked diacritics, like a with diaeresis and cedilla ä̧

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm lists the entire `Mn` category.  For the writing systems I have any knowledge about, it looks right.

Comment: Unfortunately, `iconv` doesn't do Unicode normalization.  There is a tool `uconv` or you can resort to Python.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/convert-between-unicode-normalization-forms-on-the-unix-command-line

Comment: Your command kind of works but the output is --Na��r-- (with 2 question marks in hexagons in case it doesn't show). Also if I do echo "--När--" directly, it doesn't. I guess that's two code point vs single code point...

Comment: Sounds like you actually don't have a properly configured UTF-8 terminal.  If a hex dump (`xxd`, `od`, `hexdump`, `hd`, what have you) of the output contains the right bytes, then the problem is basically solved.

Comment: OK, I don't think there's an easy solution with perl or bash between single/double point code. So I'm doing it like this: `A=$( echo $1 | sed -e "s/a/[aàáâãäå]/gI" -e "s/c/[cç]/gI" -e "s/d/[dð]/gI" -e "s/e/[eèéêë]/gI" -e "s/i/[iìíîï]/gI" -e "s/n/[nñ]/gI" -e "s/o/[oòóôõöø]/gI" -e "s/u/[uùúûü]/gI" -e "s/y/[yýÿ]/gI"  )` which I can then pass to `find -iregex ".*$A.*"` or `grep -Gi "$A"`. But I don't see how I can fit æ and œ in there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for a whole bunch of POSIX regex [equivalence classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Equivalence-Class-Operators.html):

> **14.3.6.2 Equivalence Class Operators (`[= … =]`)**
>
>   Regex recognizes equivalence class expressions inside lists. A
>   *equivalence class expression*
>   is a set of collating elements which all belong to the same equivalence class. You form an equivalence class expression by putting a collating element between an
>   *open-equivalence-class operator*
>   and a
>   *close-equivalence-class operator*
>   .
>   `[=`
>   represents the open-equivalence-class operator and
>   `=]`
>   represents the close-equivalence-class operator. For example, if
>   `a`
>   and
>   `A`
>   were an equivalence class, then both
>   `[[=a=]]`
>   and
>   `[[=A=]]`
>   would match both
>   `a`
>   and
>   `A`
>   . If the collating element in an equivalence class expression isn’t part of an equivalence class, then the matcher considers the equivalence class expression to be a collating symbol.

I'm using carets on the next line to indicate what is actually colored.  I also tweaked the test string to illustrate a point about case.

```bash
$ echo "I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" | grep '[[=a=]][[=e=]][[=i=]]'
I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi
        ^^^          ^^^
```

This matches all words like `aei`.  The fact that it does not match `æi` should stand as a reminder that you're beholden to whatever mapping exists in the regex library you're using (presumably gnulib, which is what I linked and quoted), though I figure it's quite likely that [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_ligature#Digraphs) are beyond the reach of even the best equivalence class map.

**You should not expect equivalence classes to be portable** as they are too arcane.

---

Taking this a step further, if you want ONLY accented characters, things get far more complicated.  Here I've changed your request for `aei` into `[aei]`.

```bash
$ echo "I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" | grep '[[=a=][=e=][=i=]]'
I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi
^  ^    ^^^     ^    ^^^ ^       ^     ^
```

Cleaning this up to avoid non-accent matches would require both equivalence classes and look-ahead/look-behind, and while BRE (basic POSIX regex) and ERE (extended POSIX regex) support the former, they both lack the latter.  Libpcre (the C library for perl-compatible regex that `grep -P` and most others use) and `perl` support the latter but lack the former:

Try #1:  `grep` with libpcre:  *failure*

```bash
$ echo "I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" \
    | grep -P '[[=a=][=e=][=i=]](?<![aei])'
grep: POSIX collating elements are not supported
```

Try #2:  `perl` itself: *failure*

```bash
$ echo "I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" \
    | perl -ne 'print if /[[=a=][=e=][=i=]](?<![aei])/'
POSIX syntax [= =] is reserved for future extensions in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[[=a=][=e= <-- HERE ][=i=]](?<![aei])/ at -e line 1.
```

Try #3:  `python` (which has its own PCRE implementation):  *(silent) failure*

```bash
$ echo "I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" \
    | python -c 'import re, sys;
                 print re.findall(r"[[=a=][=e=][=i=]]", sys.stdin.read())'
[]
```

Wow, a regex feature that PCRE, `python`, and even `perl` *don't* support!  There aren't too many of those.  (Never mind the complaint being on the *second* equivalence class, it still complains given just `/[[=a=]]/`.)  This as further evidence that equivalence classes are arcane.

In fact, it appears that there aren't *any* PCRE libraries capable of equivalence classes; the section on [equivalence classes at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#eq) claims only the regex libraries implementing the POSIX standard actually have this support.  GNU `grep` gets closest since it can do BRE, ERE, and PCRE, but it can't combine them.

So we'll do it in two parts.

Try #4:  disgusting trickery: *success*

```bash
$ echo "I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" \
    | grep --color=always '[[=a=][=e=][=i=]]' \
    | perl -pne "s/\e\[[0-9;]*m\e\[K(?i)([aei])/\$1/g"
I match àei but also äēì and possibly æi
        ^            ^^^
```

Code walk:

- `grep` forces color on so that `perl` can key on the color codes to note the matches
- `perl`'s `s///` command matches the color code (`\e…\e\[K`) then the non-accented letters that we want to remove from the final results, then it replaces all of that with the (uncolored) letters (if that's insufficient, see my [guide to removing all ANSI escape sequences](https://superuser.com/a/1388860/300293))
- Anything after `(?i)` in the `perl` regex is case-insensitve since `[[=i=]]` matches `I`
- `perl -p` prints each line of its input upon completion of its `-e` execution

---

For more on BRE vs ERE vs PCRE and others, see [this StackExchange regex post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) or the [POSIX regexps at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).  For more on per-language differences (including libpcre vs python PCRE vs perl), look to [tools at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html).

---

**2019 Updates:** GNU Grep now uses `$GREP_COLORS` which can look like `ms=1;41` which takes priority over the older `$GREP_COLOR` like `1;41`. This is harder to extract (and it's hard to juggle between the two), so I modified the perl code in try #4 to seek out *any* [SGR color code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters) instead of keying on just the color that grep would add. See [revision 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27980272/2) for the previous code.

I cannot currently verify whether [BSD grep](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep), which is used by Apple Mac OS X, supports POSIX regex equivalence classes.

Comment: The first part of your answer (match both with and without accent) is what I was looking for. I'd never heard of equivalence class before and they look simple enough. But the 2nd part is technically impressive nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't working for me, with either macOS grep or GNU grep. The first command has no output and the last one outputs the line but with nothing colored.

Comment: @nloveladyallen – If `echo = |grep '[[=a=]]'` finds that equals sign, then your grep does not support equivalence classes. Otherwise, the problem is probably with your locales and/or your system's locale support. (That's the extent of how much I can help; sorry, I'm not an expert on locales.) You could pose that as a new question, which should include the ouput of `locale` and perhaps notable selections of `locale -a`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done in grep, unless you're willing to write a shell script that uses `iconv` and `diff`, which would be a bit visually different from what you're requesting.

Here is something very close to your request via a quick perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# tgrep 0.1 Copyright 2014 by Adam Katz, GPL version 2 or later

use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Text::Unidecode;

my $regex = shift or die "Missing pattern.\nUsage: tgrep PATTERN [FILE...]";

my $retval = 1;  # default to false (no hits)

while(<>) {
  my $line = "", my $hit = 0;
  while(/\G(\S*(?:\s+|$))/g){             # for each word (w/ trailing spaces)
    my $word = $1;
    if(unidecode($word) =~ qr/$regex/) {  # if there was a match
      $hit++;                             # note that fact
      $retval = 0;                        # final exit code will be 0 (true)
      $line .= "\e[1;31m$word\e[0;0m";    # display word in RED
    } else {
      $line .= $word;                     # display non-matching word normally
    }
  }
  print $line if $hit;                    # only display lines with matches
}

exit $retval;
```

Markdown doesn't allow me to make red text, so here's the output with the hits in quotes instead:

```sh
$ echo "match àei but also äēì and possibly æi" | tgrep aei
match "àei" but also "äēì" and possibly "æi"
```

This will highlight matching *words* rather than the actual match, which would be very difficult to do without making massive character classes and/or composing a piecemeal regex parser.  Therefore, searching for the pattern "ae" instead of "aei" would produce the same results (in this case).

None of grep's flags are replicated in this toy example.  I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: See my other answer to this question for a "better" solution via [POSIX equivalence classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#eq).  The transfiguration mapping in gnulib isn't as good as perl's Text::Unidecode, but at least it's a feature within a regex implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Really quicker than the perl solution for me using grep from php (can be adapted).

Strtolower your query string with no accents, then replace some letter with their accent forms, and grep -i for case insensible researchs (take care about quotes in $q) :

```
// Your query string
$q = 'Maxime Bernié';

$accents = array(
    'a' => '[aáàâäãå]',
    'e' => '[eéèêë]',
    'i' => '[iíìîï]',
    'o' => '[oóòôöõ]',
    'u' => '[uúùûü]',
    'c' => '[cç]',
    'n' => '[nñ]',
    'y' => '[ýÿ]'
);

$q = remove_accents(strtolower($q));
$qa = str_split($q);

foreach ($qa as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($accents[$v])) {
        $qa[$k] = $accents[$v];
    }
}

$q = implode('', $qa);

echo system('cat file.txt | grep -i "'.$q.'"');

function remove_accents($str, $charset='utf-8')
{
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, $charset);

    $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z])(?:acute|cedil|caron|circ|grave|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);#', '\1', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z]{2})(?:lig);#', '\1', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('#&[^;]+;#', '', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: This solution would require maintaining that `$accents` map by hand.  If you think that would suffice, 1ổꝺƙ ḁŧ ᵺȋṩ (text I found in a spam).